# In MySQL, CHAR() function works weird

Tags: mysql, char

When I write CHAR() function.
For example:

```
mysql> select char(97);
+--------------------+
| char(97)           |
+--------------------+
| 0x61               |
+--------------------+
```

I know that this is not right.

```
mysql> select char(97);
+--------------------+
| char(97)           |
+--------------------+
| a                  |
+--------------------+
```

Maybe this is right situation, right?

Can you explain how can I fix this problem?

Comment: That is the hex value of `a`. Maybe related to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99480

Comment: As mentioned above, `0x` means the value is in hexadecimal, and `0x61` is `91` in decimal...  Also, what version of mysql are you using?  What are you using to run your queries (Linux command line, a sql gui, etc)? It seems fine here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=710cce9fa38003975bb612e3f5a820a0

Comment: i use 8.0.22 version and i use mamp in Mac

Answer (score 4):

Prior to MySQL 8.0.19, the issue which you are facing did not exist. `binary-as-hex` client option is enabled by default from MySQL 8.0.19.

Run `status` or `\s` in MySQL. You will notice a line about binary data. If it is mentioned as hexadecimal, outputs of functions like `CHAR()` and `UNHEX()` will displayed as hexadecimal instead of normal text.

To avoid this you can use the USING charset clause of `CHAR()`.

```
mysql> SELECT CHAR(97);
+--------------------+
| CHAR(97)           |
+--------------------+
| 0x61               |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CHAR(97 USING utf8mb4);
+------------------------+
| CHAR(97 USING utf8mb4) |
+------------------------+
| a                      |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or, you can use `--skip-binary-as-hex`. The steps to follow in Windows are:

1. Open Command Prompt.
2. Change the directory. In my case the command was:

   ```
   cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin"
   ```
3. Run

   ```
   mysql -u root -p --skip-binary-as-hex
   ```
4. Enter the password.
5. Now, the outputs of `CHAR()` function will be as you expect it to be.

**Note**: The `--skip-binary-as-hex` method works until you quit MySQL. You need to use `--skip-binary-as-hex` method every time you open MySQL such that hexadecimal values will not be shown.

You can refer these links for more information:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_binary-as-hex

Answer (score 2):

Although answer given by @RandomPerson is correct I don't think `USING utf8mb4` should be the recommended way to approach the problem.

The `CHAR()` function only accepts `ASCII` values. Arguments larger than 255 are converted into multiple result bytes.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_ascii

> CHAR() arguments larger than 255 are converted into multiple result bytes. For example, CHAR(256) is equivalent to CHAR(1,0), and CHAR(256*256) is equivalent to CHAR(1,0,0):
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT HEX(CHAR(1,0)), HEX(CHAR(256));
> +----------------+----------------+
> | HEX(CHAR(1,0)) | HEX(CHAR(256)) |
> +----------------+----------------+
> | 0100           | 0100           |
> +----------------+----------------+
> mysql> SELECT HEX(CHAR(1,0,0)), HEX(CHAR(256*256));
> +------------------+--------------------+
> | HEX(CHAR(1,0,0)) | HEX(CHAR(256*256)) |
> +------------------+--------------------+
> | 010000           | 010000             |
> +------------------+--------------------+
> ```

Thus the recommended approach to this problem should be -

```
 SELECT CHAR(97 USING ASCII);
+----------------------+
| CHAR(97 USING ASCII) |
+----------------------+
| a                    |
+----------------------+
```

Comment: I did not exactly recommend utf8mb4. I just recommend using the *USING charset clause of `CHAR()`*.