# When I executed char(97) in MYSQL 8.0, it is showing 0x61. Why? i wanted 'a' as answer

Tags: mysql, char

When I executed char(97) in MYSQL 8.0, it is showing 0x61.char() function returns the char value of the integer passed. but here it is displaying a hexavalue.

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=710cce9fa38003975bb612e3f5a820a0 You need to provide more context, i.e a [example].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In MySQL, CHAR() function works weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65614116/in-mysql-char-function-works-weird)

Answer (score 1):

You're basically getting the exact output you expect, but your MySQL client is not fully sure of how to display it so it's playing safe.

From [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char) (emphasis mine):

> By default, **`CHAR()` returns a binary string**. To produce a string in a given character set, use the optional USING clause:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT CHARSET(CHAR(X'65')), CHARSET(CHAR(X'65' USING utf8));
> +----------------------+---------------------------------+
> | CHARSET(CHAR(X'65')) | CHARSET(CHAR(X'65' USING utf8)) |
> +----------------------+---------------------------------+
> | binary               | utf8                            |
> +----------------------+---------------------------------+
> ```